# MVC validating change password. current password vs new password

Tags: model-view-controller

In Change password there should be 1. current password 2. New Password and 3. confirm password against single user. 
I need a code to validate current password vs new password.
If the current password and new password is same , should throw an error of 'password already exist please choose another'

Answer (score 0):

The function could for example look like:

```
void validatePassword(string currentpw, string newpw)
{
   if (newpw == currentpw)
      throw new Exception("Password already exist please 
choose another");
}
```

Now that's very out of context